# code igniter with flex is it good combination?

Tags: php, apache-flex, codeigniter

im looking forward flex php developers about their works with CI and flex combination.

did you guys feels good and keep things innovative

and im just looking for working samples you have or you came across .
Thanxs,
Gobi :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter works great when integrating the AMFPHP library.  The AMFPHP library is not only faster than regular POST/GET requests, it also allows you to pass PHP objects into Flex objects and Flex to PHP.  Integration example is on the CI wiki here http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Amfphp_and_CI/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why shouldn't it? Flex is just a flash-based web application framework. CodeIgniter is just a PHP-based framework. Just like HTML and Javascript, the only time when the two communicate is on POST or GET requests. Just like in Javascript, you can use XML, JSON, simple strings, or any other data type to communicate back and forth.